# Using GIS (Google Identity Services) and API Subpackage (picker) without client package

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

I am currently replacing the `gapi.oauth2` package, by using the `TokenClient` according to the [guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis) and everything works fine.

```html
global.google.accounts.oauth2
        .initTokenClient({
            client_id: CONFIG.google.clientId,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
            ux_mode: 'popup',
            callback(tokenResponse) {
                if (tokenResponse && !tokenResponse.error) {
                    onSuccess(tokenResponse.access_token);

                    return;
                }

                onError(tokenResponse.error || 'google authentication failed');
            },
        })
        .requestAccessToken({});
```

The only issue is that we are not using the `gapi.client` and would prefer avoiding loading that package as we are only using the token to show a picker by using `google.picker.PickerBuilder`.
Now after the initialization the GSI package tries to use `gapi.client.setToken()` which obviously fails as the package is not loaded.

[[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Set token failed. Gapi.client.setToken undefined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGZjy.png)

So now i could not find anything in the reference on how to prevent that call to happen, nor how to at least suppress the warning by not e.g hacking in a `noop` as a placeholder.

Does anyone know if there is any official way to deal with that ?

Answer (score 1):

In my tests the access token is successfully returned to the callback handler.

It looks to be an incorrectly generated warning, annoying yes, but functionally you're okay.  A later, official release should remove the warning with no action on your part required.

Answer (score 1):

The new API of GIS (Google Identity Services) maybe remove the setToken of the gapi.
I had to fix it by the code.

```
gapi = {client: {setToken: function(){ return; }}};
```